# Knockout viewmodel function affects only the last instance

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, underscore.js, viewmodel

What I try to achieve is to instantiate multiple viewmodels (number is variable) but a function bind at click only affects the last instance no matter from where I click.

**JS**

```
function Photo(name){
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
}

function SectionPhotosViewModel() {
    var self = this;  

    // Editable data
    self.photos = ko.observableArray([
        {
            name: 'smth'
        },
        {
            name: 'smth else'
        }
    ]);

    // Operations
    self.addPhoto = function() {
        self.photos.push(new Photo('anything'));
    }
}

function bindSectionPhotos(element, index, list){
    ko.applyBindings(SectionPhotosViewModel, element);
}

_.each(document.querySelectorAll( 'fieldset.room' ), bindSectionPhotos)
```

**HTML**

```
<fieldset class="room">
    <div data-bind="click: addPhoto;" class="btn btn-success">Add new</div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: photos">
        <li data-bind="text: name"></div>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="room">
    <div data-bind="click: addPhoto;" class="btn btn-success">Add new</div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: photos">
        <li data-bind="text: name"></div>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="room">
    <div data-bind="click: addPhoto;" class="btn btn-success">Add new</div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: photos">
        <li data-bind="text: name"></div>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="room">
    <div data-bind="click: addPhoto;" class="btn btn-success">Add new</div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: photos">
        <li data-bind="text: name"></div>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

And whatever button I click, only the last intance is modified. Ideeas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *constructor* function which you reference without the `new` keyword, thus always referring to the function definition. Try this instead:

```
function bindSectionPhotos(element, index, list){
    ko.applyBindings(new SectionPhotosViewModel(), element);
}
```

Here's a full demo:

```js
function Photo(name) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = name;
}

function SectionPhotosViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.photos = ko.observableArray([
    { name: 'smth' }, 
    { name: 'smth else' }]);

  self.addPhoto = function() {
    self.photos.push(new Photo('anything'));
  }
}

function bindSectionPhotos(element, index, list) {
  ko.applyBindings(new SectionPhotosViewModel(), element);
}

_.each(document.querySelectorAll('fieldset.room'), bindSectionPhotos)
```

```css
.btn { background: #eee; padding: 5px; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<fieldset class="room">
  <div data-bind="click: addPhoto;" class="btn btn-success">Add new</div>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: photos">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="room">
  <div data-bind="click: addPhoto;" class="btn btn-success">Add new</div>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: photos">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="room">
  <div data-bind="click: addPhoto;" class="btn btn-success">Add new</div>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: photos">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```